# Is electron app needs chromium during development in ubuntu

Tags: electron, electron-forge

i am new to electron js and i created a simple app that opens whatsapp web.

First it works perfectly but i dont have chromium at that time. Then i use electron forge so i created a new app with the same code and i have chromium this time.

But the output varies
[image]

link for the code is here => https://github.com/gowtham758550/WA-opener

Is chrome needed or chromium is ok for running a electron app

i am a beginner help me to solve this

Comment: Did you find the solution? If my answer helped please upvote or accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the user-agent.

A user-agent is just a string that Whatsapp uses to detect what OS and browser you're coming from. Currently the user-agent looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) wa-opener/1.0.0 Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Electron/12.0.2 Safari/537.36
```

Notice how Electron adds `wa-opener/1.0.0`?

Taking `wa-opener/1.0.0` out of the user-agent fixes it.

We can change the user-agent with this code:

```js
var session = require('electron').session;
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(function (detailsObj, callbackFunc) {
    detailsObj.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = detailsObj.requestHeaders['User-Agent'].replace(/wa-opener\/[.0-9]+ /, '');
    callbackFunc({requestHeaders: detailsObj.requestHeaders});
});
```

That'll take `wa-opener/1.0.0` out of the user-agent and voila!

Comment: still the same output asks to update chrome :(

Comment: @gowtham758550 I've updated my answer, see if that works for you :)